# Почему строковые функции PHP substr и substr_replace портят последний символ в строке?

Tags: php, база-данных, unicode

Ограничиваю вводимые данные перед занесением в БД с помощью функции `substr`:

```
$string = "Lorem Ipsum - это текст-рыба, часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной рыбой для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.";    
$test = substr($string, 0, 150);
```

При записи в БД получаю ошибку: `General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xD0' for column ...`

Смотрю на вывод функции `substr` и вижу юникод в конце строки: `Lorem Ipsum - это текст-рыба, часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является �`

Насколько понимаю, проблема не в кодировке, так как задана UTF-8, кроме того, юникод появляется не всегда, но только на определенных значениях длины текста; если я укажу, например, `$test = substr($string, 0, 120);`, юникод не появляется. При использовании функции `substr_replace` результат аналогичный.

Прошу совета, как решить задачу ограничения длины строки и почему в конце строки появляется юникод?

Comment: Для utf-8 функции особенные http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: `substr` отрезает не `code point`ы, а байты

Comment: @Visman, попробовал `mb_substr` и получил аналогичный результат с юникодом в конце.

Comment: @rjhdby , чем можно её заменить?

Comment: А установить 4й параметр функции ни как? :) Или `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` в начале кода.

Comment: И еще можно добавить `mb_language('uni'); mb_substitute_character(0xFFFD);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Смотрю на вывод функции substr и вижу юникод в конце строки: Lorem
>   Ipsum - это текст-рыба, часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне.
>   Lorem Ipsum является �

� – Вы называете это «юникодом», но это неправильное понимание вещей. Это не «юникод», а символ, который получился в результате неверной разбивки **многобайтового** символа на части.

Дело в том, что UTF-8 символы содержат от 1 до 4 байт, а функция `substr` отрезает строку по байтам (она предназначена для **однобайтовых** кодировок). Поэтому в некоторых случаях функция `substr` разрезает юникод-последовательность на две части. Тогда и получаются такие «кракозяблы»: � :)

Для правильной работы с многобайтовыми кодировками используйте функции с префиксом `mb_`. В данном случае используйте [mb_substr()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php) вместо `substr`.

Перед использованием `mb_`-функций следует сделать вызов:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

– это нужно для того, чтобы указать конкретную многобайтовую кодировку, с которой будет идти работа в `mb_`-функциях.

В некоторых случаях `mb_substr` и `substr` будут давать одинаковый результат. Например, если входная строка состоит из однобайтовых символов («Hello World!» – здесь все символы состоят из одного байта). Тем не менее, при работе с многобайтовыми кодировками следует всегда использовать `mb_substr`, а не полагаться на набор символов в строке.